# Changing gradient legend label of GOChord?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Does anyone know how can I change in R the title of the gradient legend of a chordplot like this?

[image]

I'm using this command to create the plot:

```
GOChord(chord, space = 0.02, gene.order = 'logFC', gene.space = 0.25, gene.size = 5,lfc.col=c("#FF0000","#FFFFFF","#0000FF"), 
        ribbon.col =c("#E31A1C", "cornflowerblue","green4", "#6A3D9A","#FF7F00","skyblue2", "#FB9A99",
        "palegreen2", "maroon",  "deeppink1", "yellow", "steelblue4","#ACC454",
        "darkturquoise", "gray56", "brown" ))
```

I'm using Log2FC so I want to write that instead of LogFC.